# SQL: Trying to find total of one column and who has the highest value in that column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

Link of tables:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1df4zUTI6e5Rw8mJxZKkOWLBuRYzjAOPkkf8zsC_2mRo/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to write a query that displays the total (sum) of all the salaries in the salary column and the name of the individual who has the highest salary.
I used:

```
select name as highest_paid,sum(salary) as total_salary 
from uscis,employer 
where uscis.alienno=employer.alienno and salary=(select max(salary) from employer) group by name
```

I did get the result of name of the highest salary paid but i did not get the sum of the salary columns. I instead got 280,000 which is the highest salary.

My apologies in advance if I worded this question poorly.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation *in the question*.

Comment: My apologies. I provided the sample data via google docs link. I am attempting to write a SQL query for the following questions: Display total salary and who makes the highest salary.  My expected result is Jeff makes the highest salary and the total of all the salaries is: 780,000

Comment: Which oracle version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using oracle XE184.

Answer (score 1):

So you do not want just the one persons salary?  You want to sum the whole salary column from the Employer table?  Assuming a 1:1 relationship between USCIS table and Employer, try this.

```
SELECT name as highest_paid, sum(salary) OVER() as everybodys_total_salary 
FROM uscis
INNER JOIN employer 
  on uscis.alienno=employer.alienno
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Description of oracle sum as an analytic function found here https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sum-analytic-function

Comment: None of this seem to work. I am very new to this. I'm using SQL Plus on Oracle which looks almost like the command prompt. I am trying to find the sum of salary column on the employer table and name of the person with the highest salary. Name of the person is not on the same table that the salary column is in. The name column is on the uscis table. Both the uscis table and the employer table share AlienNo column which i will be using to get the name. The query that I typed in does give me the name of the highest paid but it does not give me the sum of the salary column.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax (you need to remove the square brackets around the identifiers and use `FETCH FIRST ROW [ONLY|WITH TIES]` instead of `LIMIT`); however, if you fix that then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Want to get the sum(salary) and max(salary) together?

```sql
with total as (
    select sum(salary) as sum_salary from employer
), max as (
    select a.name, b.salary from uscis a, employer b where a.alienno = b.alienno and b.salary = (select max(salary) from employer)
)
select * from max, total;
```

look at the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04a28fa5b25e593b5aedc6a8b39cea72)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` as an analytic function and the `ORDER BY` the salary in `DESC`ending order and get only the first row:

```sql
SELECT name as highest_paid,
       SUM(salary) OVER () as total_salary 
FROM   uscis
       INNER JOIN employer 
       ON ( uscis.alienno=employer.alienno )
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
-- or FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY if you only ever want one row.
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE uscis ( AlienNo, Name, Nationality, City ) AS
SELECT 'A1023', 'Jeff',  'India',   'Atlanta'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1024', 'David', 'China',   'NY'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1025', 'Mark',  'UK',      'Charlotte' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2050', 'Shown', 'Germany', 'Astoria'   FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employer ( AlienNo, SSN, Dept, Salary ) AS
SELECT 'A1023', '111-22-4567', 'EE', 280000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1024', '333-32-8767', 'CS', 180000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1025', '444-45-3454', 'CE', 140000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2050', '234-34-2234', 'ME',    180.000 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> HIGHEST_PAID | TOTAL_SALARY
> :----------- | -----------:
> Jeff         |       600180
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f33ec8435bd276023be3979f6a59d186)*